# Implementation of 32 bit ALU in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

i am implementing  32 bit ALU in VHDL. i found an error. i can't understand  why i am getting this..
which is 
    Cannot update 'in' object out_alu

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
 ----==== Entity of AlU with input and Output 
 entity AlU is  Port (
   A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);       ---== A input   Vector with 32 Bit 
   B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);       ---== B input   Vector with 32 Bit 
   S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0) ;       ---== S select  Input Vector 3 bit for operation  
   out_AlU : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));---== Output of AlU 32 
 end AlU;

 architecture Behavioral of AlU is
 begin

 Select_for_operation: Process (S)   ---= Deffierent  Process for AlU with the     selection of S
                  begin
                                Case S is  
                                when     "000" =>  
                                          out_AlU <=A xor  B ;
                                when   "001"=> 
                                          out_AlU <=A Xnor B ;
                                when   "100"=> 
                                          out_AlU <=A  or  B ; 
                                when   "101"=> 
                                         out_AlU  <=A  nor B ;
                                when   "110"=> 
                                         out_AlU  <=A  and B ;
                                when    others => 
                                                    NULL ;      
                                end case ;
                        end Process ;
 end Behavioral;
```

Comment: `out_Alu` is declared as `in`. This is what's causing the "can't update" error.

Comment: Thank you so much ,,,@nvlass  .. this is very small error but i coud'nt detec it

Comment: The sensitivity list of Select_for_operation should also include A and B. Otherwise you might have simulation mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your signal out_ALU is declared as an input to your entity. That's why you can't assign a signal to it (it is read only so to say).

Change it to out and it will likely compile:

```
 entity AlU is  Port (
   A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);       ---== A input   Vector with 32 Bit 
   B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);       ---== B input   Vector with 32 Bit 
   S : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0) ;       ---== S select  Input Vector 3 bit for operation  
   out_AlU : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));---== Output of AlU 32 
 end AlU;
```